# How to get selected 1st radio button by default and get values of it in angular

Tags: html, angular, radio-button, angular8

```
<form>
<ul>
<li class="filter-list" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem == item}" (click)="listCategory($event, item)" *ngFor="let item of category"><input class="pixel-radio" type="radio" [id]="item" name="category">
<label [for]="item">{{ item }}</label></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

This is my HTML CODE

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {

  category:string[]=["Laptop","Mobile","TV","Camera"];
  products: Products[]=[];
  selectedCategory:string;
  cart: Cart;
  brand:["Acer","Asus","Dell","HP","Lenovo"];

listCategory(event, newValue)
{
this.selectedCategory=newValue
}
```

But by default value is not coming in it This is my all default values in typescript file

Comment: You’re mixing things here.. do you want the li to be the active thing or the radio..? Or both? You can set the selected radio by adding [checked]=“selectedItem === item” to your input..

Comment: Not working Bro I want 1st radio button to be checked but [checked]=“selectedItem === item” is not working for me

Comment: Are you setting the selectedItem to the first item in your component?

Comment: No how to do it can you tell me

Comment: Your seem to have a bit of a disconnect between your template and your component. Is this.category the same as selectedItem..? Not enough code here to determine.

Comment: I have updated my code check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following stackblitz link:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/rllllvapblod?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-harness-example.html

You need to have the attribute 'checked' to true or false for the first item

So your HTML will become like this:

```
<form>
   <ul>
    <li class="filter-list" 
        [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem == item}" 
       (click)="listCategory($event, item)" 
       *ngFor="let item of category; let i=index"
    >
           <input class="pixel-radio" 
                  type="radio" 
                 [id]="item" name="category"
                 [checked]="i===0" // Add this line
           >
           <label [for]="item">{{ item }}</label>
     </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Why on earth do you not use [(ngModel)] or ReactiveForms? Angular guys put an enormous effort to facilitate the binding between variables and html inputs and looks like nobody appreciate it :(

Answer (score 0):

Here you can show the clicked value and the first value from the array of data as checked by default.

"[checked]" this will check the radio button on condition. Showing the first value as checked by default and once the user selects some value from the array, the radio button should be active/checked on that particular data, even by going from the radio button page to some other page and coming back to the radio button page.

HTML :-

```
    <div class="sections" (click)="setRadioCheckedOnClicked(passenger.id)" *ngFor="let passenger of passDetail; let i = index" >
<input type="radio" name="person-selector" [checked]="passenger.Id === checkedId"/>
</div>
```

.ts :-

```
this.checkedId = any;

constructor(){
this.checkedId = sessionStorage.getItem('checkedId')
}

setRadioCheckedOnClicked(value:any){
 if (this.checkedId === '' || this.checkedId === undefined || this.checkedId === null) {
      this.checkedId = value
    } else {
      this.checkedId = sessionStorage.getItem('checkedId')
    }
}
```

1. In the above example `[checked]="passenger.Id === checkedId"` passenger.id is complete array value and checkedId holds value which we get from storage or the 1st value which we bind from array if the storaged value is null.
2. setRadioCheckedOnClicked(value:any) Call this in your api response method which will display the data on load of the page.